# Rails 5 Action Cable not working in Google Cloud (VM)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, notifications, google-cloud-platform, actioncable

I am using rails 5 for actioncable. I have developed and tested application with actioncable on my local machine (in development environment). The real time notification work perfectly until I try to deploy the code to virtual machine on Google cloud server.

I know Google cloud may use different ports, like 2525 for email server,  from the norm(my common practice).  Is that Google cloud using different port for Rails 5 actioncable ?

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) do |repo_name|
  repo_name = "#{repo_name}/#{repo_name}" unless repo_name.include?("/")
  "https://github.com/#{repo_name}.git"
end
ruby '2.4.2'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.1.4'
gem 'puma', '~> 3.7'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
  gem 'capybara', '~> 2.13'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
end
group :development do
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
gem 'bootstrap', '~> 4.0.0.alpha6'
gem 'devise'
gem 'high_voltage'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'mysql2', '~> 0.3.18'
gem 'therubyracer', :platform=>:ruby
group :development do
  gem 'better_errors'
  gem 'rails_layout'
end
gem 'jquery-datatables-rails', '~> 3.4.0'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails', '~>5.0'
gem 'passenger'
gem 'devise-i18n'
#gem 'translated_attribute_value'
gem 'paperclip'
gem 'aasm'
gem 'validates_timeliness'
gem 'momentjs-rails'
gem 'delayed_job_active_record'
gem 'delayed_job'
gem 'daemons'
gem 'ransack'
gem 'will_paginate'
gem 'will_paginate-bootstrap'
gem 'whenever', :require => false
gem "rmagick"
gem 'carrierwave'
#gem "mini_magick"
gem "fog-google"
gem "google-api-client"
gem "mime-types"
gem 'serviceworker-rails'
gem "binding_of_caller"
gem 'chartkick'
gem 'groupdate'
gem 'active_median'
gem 'cocoon'
gem 'geocoder'
gem 'pdfkit'
gem 'render_anywhere'
gem 'wkhtmltopdf-binary'
gem 'toastr-rails'
gem 'simple_form'
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
gem 'bootstrap-glyphicons'
gem 'datetimepicker-rails', github: 'zpaulovics/datetimepicker-rails', branch: 'master', submodules: true
gem 'sprockets'
gem 'jquery-turbolinks'
```

Comment: At least you should share your `Gemfile` here. The `ActionCable` requires an event-based web server, so your production stack should fit with that requirement.

Comment: Currently, I am still testing with the development environment.